# php built-in server redirecting to localhost on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to run a fresh install of wordpress using the php built-in sever via

`php  -S localhost:8000`

When I visit `localhost:8000` or the port number I supplied during creation it redirects me to `localhost` which is the default apache page. Meaning it basically hands control over to apache which is what I am avoiding in the first place. I have ran the same command in other php projects (laravel) and it works just fine. I am new to wordpress what up with it and this error?

For the record, I hate working from `/var/www/html` directory because it's annoying to deal with permissions during developement. I prefer to keep all my projects in a "projects" folder and serve on ports without any server hassle just like other langs like js (node).

*I am on Ubuntu 16.04*

Comment: Probably because you installed WordPress into `localhost` and WP saves the domain it was installed into in its database and uses it in all sorts of odd and anoying places

Comment: There should be a setting in your WP admin to change the base URL to include the port number?

Comment: I should try a new install without using localhost and apache then report back.

Comment: Well that does not seem to be the case, just tried a fresh install it does same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the URLs in the admin panel, so they contain your localhost with the required port:
[image]

Alternatively, you can define the site url in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

More information is available with [Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL).