# Built-in PHP server redirecting to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, localhost

I installed PHP 7.4 and MySQL using Homebrew. I originally configured the local WordPress site’s address to the remote one but realized I made a mistake. So, I deleted the `wp-config.php` and ran the installation again and pointed the site and WordPress address to the local one. They are set to http://localhost:8000. Now, the local site keeps redirecting from localhost:8000 to localhost. The Dashboard works fine but when I try to navigate to the site, it keeps redirecting to localhost.

I already tried [this](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/) but it didn’t work. I also searched for other similar questions here on Stackoverflow and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612593/php-built-in-server-redirecting-to-localhost-on-wordpress) but it doesn't have an answer that worked. I can't comment on other questions because I don't have enough reputation.

I've tried clearing Chrome's cache. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the PHP formula and its dependencies. I've tried using Safari to load the site and it worked. I've tried disabling browser extensions. I've tried editing wp-config.php as suggested [here](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/). I also tried loading the site in an incognito Chrome browser and it worked.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried clearing Chrome's cache. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the PHP formula and its dependencies. I've tried using Safari to load the site and it worked. I've tried disabling browser extensions. I've also tried editing wp-config.php as suggested here: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: There you go. I have also reported this to Google by using the Report an Issue on the browser.

Comment: Keep in mind that 301 redirects are [cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s) by your browsers. Try to clear the full cache and test again

Comment: Do you think it's the Site Settings? I cleared the History and cache before.

Comment: You mean that the 301 is stored in the site settings of your browser? Dunno about that, only know that doing `CTRL + F5` will not get the job done, more info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.